# How to make PDF from React?

Tags: reactjs

I am going to use jsPDF library in React.JS but it got error, please let me know if someone get my query. I was trying to this more than 2 days but I can't.

Comment: Yes it can, you can upload the sample code that you are using.

Comment: What you have tried? What kind of error?

Comment: it solved, please have a look solution.

Comment: See also: [Generating a PDF file from React Components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44989119/562769)

Comment: Based on this question I wrote a brief tutorial about this topic: [React Component to PDF](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step1:

Package.json
dependencies

`"jspdf": "git://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/#76edb3387cda3d5292e212765134b06150030364"`,

This is due to jspdf for npm is not working.

Step2:

Add print function:

```js
onPrint() {
    const { vehicleData } = this.props.parkedVehicle;
    const { 


    plate_no,
      max_time,
      entry_date_time,
      exit_date_time,
      expiry_time,
      address1,
      address2,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
      country,
      parking_status
    } = vehicleData;

    var pdfConverter = require('jspdf');
    //var converter = new pdfConverter();
    //var doc = converter.jsPDF('p', 'pt');

    var doc = new pdfConverter('p','pt','c6');

    doc.setFontSize(22);
    doc.text(20, 50, 'Park Entry Ticket');
    doc.setFontSize(16);
    doc.text(20, 80, 'Address1: ' + address1);
    doc.text(20, 100, 'Address2: ' + address2);
    doc.text(20, 120, 'Entry Date & time: ' + entry_date_time);
    doc.text(20, 140, 'Expiry date & time: ' + exit_date_time);
    doc.save("test.pdf");
}
```

And It worked fine to me.

Comment: If anyone sees this in 2019, I'm trying to use this code but it says that "props" is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

We can now also convert React components directly to pdf.

The idea is to pass the react-rendered through following transformation: 
DOM -> CANVAS -> PNG -> PDF

For DOM to Canvas, we can use the html2canvas library. Canvas to PNG is straight forward. From PNG to PDF, we can use jsDom.

I've posted an answer explaining the same with more details and code samples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017234/1587695).

Comment: By this method can the text on created pdf be copied ?

Comment: Using this method, the pdf is constructed of images so the text is not selectable.

Answer (score 1):

1 => import  import { PDFExport, savePDF } from '@progress/kendo-react-pdf';

```
import { PDFExport, savePDF } from '@progress/kendo-react-pdf';
```

2 => create download button

```
      <button id='print-btn' className="btn btn-danger me-2" onClick={() => downloadAsPdf()}>Download</button>

 const downloadAsPdf = (e) => {
    savePDF(pdfExportComponent.current, { paperSize: "A3" }); }
```

3 => Create a ref

```
      const pdfExportComponent = React.useRef(null);
```

4=> this is your component

```
     <div id='PrintDocument' ref={pdfExportComponent}>
                            <div class="container ">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        Invoice
                                        <strong>01/01/01/2018</strong>
                                        <span class="float-right"> <strong>Status:</strong> Pending</span>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row mb-4">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <h6 class="mb-3">From:</h6>
                                                <div>
                                                    <strong>Webz Poland</strong>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>Madalinskiego 8</div>
                                                <div>71-101 Szczecin, Poland</div>
                                                <div>Email: info@webz.com.pl</div>
                                                <div>Phone: +48 444 666 3333</div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <h6 class="mb-3">To:</h6>
                                                <div>
                                                    <strong>Bob Mart</strong>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>Attn: Daniel Marek</div>
                                                <div>43-190 Mikolow, Poland</div>
                                                <div>Email: marek@daniel.com</div>
                                                <div>Phone: +48 123 456 789</div>
                                            </div>



                                        </div>

                                        <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th class="center">#</th>
                                                        <th>Item</th>
                                                        <th>Description</th>

                                                        <th class="right">Unit Cost</th>
                                                        <th class="center">Qty</th>
                                                        <th class="right">Total</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="center">1</td>
                                                        <td class="left strong">Origin License</td>
                                                        <td class="left">Extended License</td>

                                                        <td class="right">$999,00</td>
                                                        <td class="center">1</td>
                                                        <td class="right">$999,00</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="center">2</td>
                                                        <td class="left">Custom Services</td>
                                                        <td class="left">Instalation and Customization (cost per hour)</td>

                                                        <td class="right">$150,00</td>
                                                        <td class="center">20</td>
                                                        <td class="right">$3.000,00</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="center">3</td>
                                                        <td class="left">Hosting</td>
                                                        <td class="left">1 year subcription</td>

                                                        <td class="right">$499,00</td>
                                                        <td class="center">1</td>
                                                        <td class="right">$499,00</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="center">4</td>
                                                        <td class="left">Platinum Support</td>
                                                        <td class="left">1 year subcription 24/7</td>

                                                        <td class="right">$3.999,00</td>
                                                        <td class="center">1</td>
                                                        <td class="right">$3.999,00</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5">

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5 ml-auto">
                                                <table class="table table-clear">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="left">
                                                                <strong>Subtotal</strong>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="right">$8.497,00</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="left">
                                                                <strong>Discount (20%)</strong>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="right">$1,699,40</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="left">
                                                                <strong>VAT (10%)</strong>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="right">$679,76</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="left">
                                                                <strong>Total</strong>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="right">
                                                                <strong>$7.477,36</strong>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use html2pdf.js npm instead of jspdf. it is easy to use and more bug free
although internally it use jspdf