# How to create PDF file and dowload in react js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, download

I am working on react ja project which is contains pdf file download. I have list view which is contains some get service data from the api, exactly on the list view I have download button. If I click on the download button the list view should download as pdf file.

I have no idea how to that, so how to generate pdf file in react js?

Comment: I haven't done this on the client side, but I just wrote a little script using pdfkit. Have a poke around http://pdfkit.org/, might help get you started.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf client side generation of PDFs

Comment: check this once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4798tj

Answer (score 0):

There are two older answers for this in **stackoverfow**.

First one is this.
[How to make PDF from React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849055/how-to-make-pdf-from-react)

Second one is how to use `jsPDF` properly. And there is a working `jsfiddle` example allso. Refer them.
[How to properly use jsPDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library)