# how to add external library to reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

what are the various options to add an external JS library to reactjs component? for example, if we have any library file such as example.js and it is used by only one react component then i would like to either add this library at index.html or at the component level. I would like to know how to include at component level.

Comment: `import` or `require` ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hosted Client-Side Libraries**

If you want to import a client-side hosted library your only option is to include it in index.html

For instance, if we wanted to include D3 in one of our components, we could add `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>` to `/public/index.html`
Then to use it from inside your component, you need to call `window.d3` instead of just `d3`

**Non-Hosted client-side libraries**

If you have a library that is not hosted, you could always save it to it's own file. once you do that, simply import it like you would any other local file `import some_library from "./path/to/some/library"`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a component that inserts the script to the header of your site. For example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ExternalLibrary = () => {

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (typeof window !== "undefined"){

            // Make sure it only gets included once.
            if (!document.getElementById("externalLibrary")){
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.id='externalLibrary'
                script.type = 'text/javascript';                
                script.src = `https://externallibrary.com/example.js`; 

                // Call some function from the library when it loads.
                script.onload = function() {                    
                    window.someFunction()
                };
                
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
            }
            
        }
    }, []);

    return null;

}  
 
export default ExternalLibrary;
```

Then you can just include this in your App.js, or other components.

Comment: Tried this solution, seems that it cannot find the function when calling window.functionName()

Answer (score 0):

By "external libraries" I'm assuming you're talking about `npm`/`yarn` repository libraries, for example:

`$ npm install moment` (Moment.js)

In those cases, you want to import it as:

`import moment from 'moment'`

Another example from the same package can be seen [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2608)

Comment: @Jagdeet , I do not have code to share. Basically , i am still figuring out how to include external libraries.

Comment: I am referring to libraries not in NPM/Yarn. I am wonderig how to include them.

Comment: What library are you trying to include? After the method I gave, you can use it, in this case moment.js: `let myTime = moment('2018-04-14'); `

Answer (score 0):

1. Easiest way is to find out whether your external library has an npm module, if so you can simply do an `npm install`.
2. Else you can add the link to this library in your `index.html`.
3. Otherwise you can download the files of your external library and use it inside as if its your own code(better checkout whether its free library to do that). In this case you can simply `import` the file

Comment: I do not want to go with the option of including in index.html. I want to confine the import at component level. one option i have is to use the following codeimport React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "./jwplayer-8.3.5/jwplayer.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1> Hello </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

Comment: Before running npm install, where do you place the external library?

Answer (score -1):

You can use like that :

```
import abc from './abc.js'
```

Check here : [How to include external javascript library in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066508/how-to-include-external-javascript-library-in-reactjs)

Comment: thanks Jagjeet for quick reply. The above import does not work for external libraries.

Comment: He explicitly asked for external libraries.