# Sending emails with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, smtp

I am trying to use an API for sending emails with JavaScript, it's called SmptJs. The API works perfectly when integrated in a simple HTML file, but I don't know how to integrate it in a reactJs component!

Here is the API link and doc: https://smtpjs.com/

I tried it first in my HTML page, like this: [code of html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBI6d.png)

And it worked, I received the email.
But I want to add the API inside my React Component, specifically when I click submit in my form but I got an error and I think it's not compatible with ReactJs syntax, here is the image:

[image: code of react component]

[image: the error msg]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add your code, it will help to debug

Comment: I just added images of my code. thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external javascript library in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066508/how-to-include-external-javascript-library-in-reactjs)

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the simple component with example here https://jsfiddle.net/92a68tmz/

You have to include the  tag of smtpjs in your public/index.html or general index.html file in your project and you can use it like this

```
 sendMail() {
     window.Email.send({
        SecureToken : "C973D7AD-F097-4B95-91F4-40ABC5567812",
        To : 'them@website.com',
        From : "you@isp.com",
        Subject : "This is the subject",
        Body : "And this is the body"
    }).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
```

in your `onSubmit` you directly use this

```
     const onSubmit = data => {
              window.Email.send({
                    SecureToken : "C973D7AD-F097-4B95-91F4-40ABC5567812",
                    To : data.email,
                    From : "you@isp.com",
                    Subject : "This is the subject",
                    Body : "And this is the body" + data.firstname
                }).then(
                    message => alert(message)
      }
```

No need for a separate Emailer component.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for me. I made a new component called Emailer and I added it in the DOM and it works. But I am stuck with something stupid, I can't add the component where I want ! can I show you an image of my code ?

Comment: Yeah @OthmanElhoufi , i am ready to help you further :)

Comment: check out the answer I just added.

Comment: If you need any other information please do tell me, I'm really stuck lol @Raja

Comment: I will look into it :)

Comment: @Hemanath  hi i am do same example  https://jsfiddle.net/92a68tmz/  but i not access data input  =>   i have text input with a name="fname"      input data.fname  it not working  
 console.log("email sending  " ,data.fname) / log output email sending   undefine
i try to send email also not working  => Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.