# How to include external javascript library (Topol.io) in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to include external JavaScript library in my ReactJS app. I am using Topol.io plugin that loads email template inside ReactJS. however, i am not i am finding difficulties in Setting state in innerHtml script.
    i am using:

```
`componentWillMount() {
    const loadScript = callback => {
      const existingScript = document.getElementById("scriptPlugin");
      if (!existingScript) {
        const scriptPlugin = document.createElement("script");
        scriptPlugin.id = "scriptPlugin";
        scriptPlugin.innerHTML = `var TOPOL_OPTIONS = {
              id: "#app",
              authorize: {
                apiKey: "xyz",
                userId: "xyz"
              },
              templateId: "${this.state.TemplateId}",
              removeTopBar: false, 
              callbacks: {
                onSaveAndClose: function(json, html) {
                  // HTML of the email
                  console.log(html);
                  // JSON object of the email
                  console.log(json);
                },
                onSave: function(json, html) {
                  console.log(json);
                  console.log(html);
                  var encodedeString = window.btoa(JSON.stringify(json));
                  // HTML of the email
                  console.log(encodedeString);
                  // JSON object of the email
                  console.log(window.atob(encodedeString));
                },
                onAutoSave($json) {
                  console.log("Auto Save");
                  "${this.setState({ demo: `{json}` })}"
                  console.log(json);
              }
              }
            };`;
        document.body.appendChild(scriptPlugin);
        const scriptLoader = document.createElement("script");
        scriptLoader.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptLoader.id = "scriptLoader";
        scriptLoader.src =
          "https://d5aoblv5p04cg.cloudfront.net/editor/loader/build.js";
        document.head.appendChild(scriptLoader);

        scriptLoader.onload = function() {
          const scriptInit = document.createElement("script");
          scriptInit.id = "scriptInit";
          scriptInit.innerHTML = `TopolPlugin.init(window.TOPOL_OPTIONS);`;
          document.body.appendChild(scriptInit);
        };
        this.setState({ loaded: true });
        scriptPlugin.onload = () => {
          // if (callback) callback();
        };
      }
    };
    loadScript(() => {});
  }
 `
```

So, i want to set the state using the variable inside or the value return by OnSave or AutoSave method.

Comment: There are a number of questions with similar titles. Have you seen them? For instance, [How to include external javascript library in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36066508/215552)...

Comment: yes. I tried to load screen using innerhtml. However, i am not able to access variable of Callback of javascript function to set state in reactjs.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your code for that process in an [mre]. Right now, this question lacks any detail and is impossible to answer. Please see [ask] for tips on how to [edit] your question to a state where it's answerable.