# Import and Use External Script in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a payment merchant in my React app which requires that I import their [v1.js](https://tpgw.trustpay.eu/js/v1.js) script and then use it to create an object.

First I tried to download the script and import it via `import ./v1.js`, but that left me with plenty of errors:

[image]

I've then imported the script in my `index.html` file instead via `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://tpgw.trustpay.eu/js/v1.js"></script>`.

This didn't incur any errors, however, the next step requires me to create an object referenced in the script using `var trustPayApi = new TrustPayApi({secrets});`.

When I run this code in my React app (substituting `secrets` for the correct value), I get an error saying

> 'TrustPayApi' is not defined

How can I correctly implement the script and use the `TrustPayApi` object defined within it?

Comment: The messages in the image are not code errors, but linting errors. They can be ignored for running the code

Comment: Apologies, I'm not familiar with those. How can I get around them?

Comment: Does this address your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802718/3977134 ?

Comment: @r3dst0rm how does that relate here?

Comment: It does indeed. I had to use the `window.` prefix when creating the `trustPayApi` object. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam in case you want to use the downloaded file rather than including a script tag in your index.html, you can exclude v1.js from linting. In your eslint config you can place a `ignorePatterns` property (for reference: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code)

Comment: @evolutionxbox OP wants to include an external script, loading it via a script tag - accessing the window property solves the "Foobar is not defined" issue.

Comment: Thanks @r3dst0rm It's good to know I can still use the script if I download it locally